# Why Are Vtables Not Being Implemented Correctly On Embedded Platform?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, embedded, vtable, freertos

I am developing code for an embedded system (specifically, the PSoC 5, using PSoC Creator), and writing in C++.

While I've overcome most hurdles with using C++ , first off compiling in C++ using the compiler flag `-x c++`, defining the new and delete operators, making sure exceptions aren't thrown with the compiler flag `-fno-exception`, I've come to a brick wall when it comes to using virtual functions.

If I try and declare a virtual function, the compiler gives me the error `undefined reference to "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info"`. The only way to get around this is to use the compiler flag `-fno-rtti`, which prevents the error and makes it compile successfully. However, if I do that, the embedded program crashes when trying to run the overloaded virtual function, and I'm thinking this is because the vtable does not exist.

I don't see why you shouldn't be able to implement vtables on an embedded platform, since all it is a extra space in memory before or after member objects (depending on the exact compiler).

The reason I am trying to use virtual functions is because I am wanting to use FreeRTOS with C++, and other people have implemented this by using virtual functions (see http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/July_2010/freertos_Is_it_possible_create_freertos_task_in_c_3778071.html for the discussion, and https://github.com/yuriykulikov/Event-driven_Framework_for_Embedded_Systems for a well written embedded C++ FreeRTOS framework)

Comment: How are you linking your executable/shared library?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by the fact that you compile for an embedded platform? Have you tried compiling the relevant parts of the code on a standard platform?

Comment: The PSoC IDE runs the linker script as part of the build process. I have included the flag `-lstdc++` to make sure it links to the standard C++ library.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the problem is due to the fact I'm using a compile sequence that was intended for an embedded platform with code written in C, and I'm missing a compiler flag or similar to get GCC to use G++ correctly. No I haven't tried compiling on a standard platform.

Comment: Are you using `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Not directly, but one thought I had was that maybe by using a virtual functions, you are calling dynamic_cast implicitly?

Comment: I don't think that will do it. You must be doing something tricky, but are unaware. Did you try a very simple example? Consider [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/nfuwVpRh). This works for me on my hosted platform. Does it work for you on your embedded platform?

Comment: I can't compile that...I can't use the std I/O functions, these use up too much memory.

Comment: Just change the `cout`s to use `puts()` instead (or in whatever way allows you to know that it actually executed).

Comment: Usually this error means that you haven't defined all non-abstract virtual methods of that class.  You should at least define a virtual destructor.  Have you checked it's not this issue?

Comment: @user315052 O.K. will do, just waiting for some spare time to test that code. No, I did not define a virtual destructor for the class. I will try that also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that the error message refers to a class named `__cxxabiv1` suggests that you are not linking against the correct **C++ runtime** for your platform. I don't know anything about PSoC, but on more "normal" platforms, this sort of error could happen if you used the `gcc` (resp. `clang`) command at link-time instead of `g++` (resp. `clang++`); or under handwavey circumstances if you used `-lc++` without `-stdlib=libc++` or `-lstdc++` without `-stdlib=libstdc++`.

Use the `-v` option to examine your linker command line, and try to find out exactly which C++ runtime library it's pulling in. It'll probably be named something like `libcxxabi` or `libcxxrt`.

[This guy here](http://cladlab.com/programming/microcontrollers/psoc/using-cplusplus-with-psoc-creator) gives step-by-step instructions for compiling C++ in PSoC Creator; but he never figured out how to link with a C++ runtime library, so all his tips are focused on how to *remove* C++isms from your code (`-fno-rtti`, `-fno-exceptions`,...). I agree that there doesn't seem to be any information online about how to actually *use* C++ with PSoC.

For this *specific* error, you could always try defining the missing symbol yourself:

```
// file "fix-link-errors.cpp"
namespace __cxxabiv1 {
    class __class_type_info {
        virtual void dummy();
    };
    void __class_type_info::dummy() { }  // causes the vtable to get created here
};
```

Or many linkers have the ability to define undefined symbols as `0x0` through command-line options such as `-C` or `--defsym`. However, that's not only a Bad Idea but also inconvenient, because you'd have to figure out what the actual (mangled) name of the vtable object is, and the linker didn't tell you that. (This being GCC, it's probably something like `__ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE`.)

Either of those "solutions" would result in horrible crashes if the program ever tried to *do* anything with the vtable; but they'd shut the linker up, if that's all you cared about and you knew the program would never actually use RTTI. But in that case, it should be sufficient to use `-fno-rtti` consistently on your entire project.

What, specifically, goes wrong when you use `-fno-rtti`?